# How does loading all pages with ajax affect the back button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a newby working on my first site. I'm using a music player that I would like to have play continuously throughout the site, so I'm researching the consequences of loading the site's various account pages with AJAX (ala Soundcloud or Spotify). I'm curious to know how this will affect the back button.

If the site is completely AJAX, when the user hits the back button to go back to (apparently) a previous account page, the site will be lost to the previous site in the browser's history. However, if Soundcloud's pages are loaded via AJAX, they've modified the back button to accommodate switching to the previously loaded AJAX page.

Answer (score 0):

well, after 5 seconds of google I found HTML5 history.pushState

EDIT.   Ended up going with rack_pjak